# WebBrowser not responding to SendKeys when called via a HotKey

Tags: c#, focus, webbrowser-control, sendkeys

Im currently trying to make an application which I can use to playback youtube videos and mute the audio using a systemwide hotkey.
The detection of the hotkey is working fine and my method to toggle the playback of the video also works as intended when I call it using a button on my form.
When however I call the togglePlayback() method from "protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)" it it will call the method but the browser will not respond to my calls.

While trying to find out what was going on I used a MessageBox to display some values. And guess what, after the message box shows up my method call works ?!

So I guess it has something to do with the fact that the msgBox that is showing up brings the whole programm back in "focus" and it registers.

But I would like to have the browser respond the the fake input at all times (when I'm in a game for example)

Methods:

```
//Used to deal with the Message you recive when a registered hotkey is pressed
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x0312 && m.WParam.ToInt32() == 1)
        {
            // Hotkey with id == 1 has been activated!
            button2_Click(button2, new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Left, 1, 12, 12, 5));
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

//Calling this method by clicking the button on the forms works, faking the call will add the text to the textbox but wont toggle anything
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        debugTextBox.Text += sender.ToString() + " -|- " + e.ToString() + "\n";
        togglePlayback();
    }

private void togglePlayback()
    {
        //If you let this msgBox pop up it will work...
        //MessageBox.Show(webBrowser1.CanSelect?"True":"False");
        debugTextBox.Text += "Playback Toggle!\n";
        webBrowser1.Document.Focus();
        SendKeys.Send("K"); //Pressing 'K' toggles pause
    }
```